# Doctrine Proxy does not initialize

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I upload a file to Symfony, it is uploads like it should. I have used the Symfony tutorial on file upload and modified it to fit my needs.

```
if($form->isValid())
{
    $em = $this->oStarter->getEntityManager();

    // Save file to database
    $uploadedFile = new ProfilePicture();
    $uploadedFile->setFile($formData["profile_picture"]);
    $user->setProfilePicture($uploadedFile);
    $uploadedFile->setUser($user);

    $em->persist($uploadedFile);
    $em->persist($user);

    $em->flush();

    // Other things like Twig templates etc..
```

This code is used to upload an image and set it as the user's profile picture. The user is found through `$this->getUser()` in the Controller. When I output the Entity after flushing, it shows me the dump of a valid Entity, like I would expect.

When I visit the profile page for this user, the image was not found. When I check the MySQL table, I find a valid entry for the ProfilePicture with the correct ID and path. The user also has a reference to the ProfilePicture's ID, as you would expect. Instead, the page shows me the following dump:

```
$avatar = $user->getProfilePicture();
$path = $avatar->getWebPath();
Debug::dump($avatar);


object(stdClass)#938 (8) 
{
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(42) "Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture"
  ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["user"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1011 (52) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(32) "Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\User"
    ["id"]=>
    int(11)
    // lots of user info
    }
  ["file"]=>
  NULL
  ["path"]=>
  NULL
  ["temp"]=>
  NULL
}
```

The dump shows that there is no path set. Even after calling a function of the Proxy, the real data seems not to be loaded. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The entities are as follows:

```
/**
 * @author Tim Cocu
 * @author Rick Slinkman
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="profilepictures")
 * @Database(target="client")
 */
class ProfilePicture extends Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="profilePicture")
     */
    private $user;

    // accessors and mutators
}

/**
 * Description of Image
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @Database(target="client")
 * @author Rick Slinkman (r.slinkman@take-a-byte.eu)
 */
class Image extends MediaFile
{
    /**
     * @param ClassMetadata $metadata
     */
    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('file', new Assert\File(array(
            'maxSize' => 6000000,
            'mimeTypes' => array(
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/png",
                "image/gif"
            ),
        )));
    }

    // other functions
}

/**
 * Standard container of an uploaded media file
 * @author Rick Slinkman
 * @author Tim Cocu
 * 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @Database(target="client")
 * 
 * Based on:
 * http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html
 */
class MediaFile 
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * Temporary storage on file moving.
     */
    protected $temp;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) 
        {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) 
        {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) 
        {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) 
        {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    // other functions 
}

/**
 * @author: Jordy - j.deruijter@take-a-byte.eu
 * @author: Rick - r.slinkman@take-a-byte.eu
 * @author: Tim - t.cocu@take-a-byte.eu
 * @since: 25-10-13
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user")
 * @Database(target="client")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    // Lots of data

    /**
     * @var ProfilePicture
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture", inversedBy="user")
     */
    protected $profilePicture;

    // Even more data
}
```

Comment: What happens when you clear your cache?

Comment: Clearing cache has no effect. I have tried clearing the prod and dev cache, but no result.

Comment: Can you add the code of your entities?

Comment: And `Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\User`? :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that one ;)

Comment: In our doctrine setup (with ZF2) we have to clear cache and proxies seperately, I have to use the ORM tool like `metadata:clear-cache` and `metadata:generate-proxies`, maybe you have to do that too?

Comment: Sadly, clearing metadata cache did not work

Comment: What did you see in `path` field in your db? try to call `getPath` on your proxy image, it will load actual data over proxy object

Comment: What happens if you change the fetch mode: `@OneToOne(targetEntity="\Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture", inversedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")`. Is the profilePicture loaded?

Comment: That was solution indeed. I have accepted and replied to a similar solution given bij @jperovic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have encountered similar error about a year ago.

You see, when you authenticate, serialized (text) version of your `User` entity is stored in your session. When you visit a page behind firewall it is being deserialized and converted to `User` again. But, since you relation to `ProfilePicture` **is NOT eager** and, during the serialization this property **is NOT serialized**. Proxy objects are not serializable...

Therefor, when it tried to retrieve authenticated user from session its `$profilePicture` property was set to `NULL`.

Could this be your case?

### IDEA #1:

1. Set relation to be `EAGER` in your `User` entity.
2. Try setting
   `always_authenticate_before_granting:  true` in your `confir.yml`
   (`security` block)

I believe this will cause security to go to database and re-fetch `User` entity on every page visit...

### IDEA #2:

Refresh your user entity and fetch `profilePicture` **manually**. Maybe you could store user profile picture in your session separately as well?

Comment: Wow, this worked! 
I tried your first idea and added eager fetching to the relation. In my `User` entity, the relation now looks like this:
`/**
     * @var ProfilePicture
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Takeabyte\CoreBundle\Entity\ProfilePicture", inversedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $profilePicture;`
After that, I cleared my cache by deleting all folders in `app/cache`. The picture showed up immediately!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just wanted to say a huge "Thank You!" for this response.  I was banging my head on my desk in frustration trying to figure out why the information was not showing up.  After using your first idea, it worked right away.  Thank you.